# React native fetch and componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to fetch some data and display on render method:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     job: {}
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
   fetch(API_URL).then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => this.setState({ job: res.job }));
}

render() {
   return (<Text>{this.state.job.name}</Text>)
}
```

But when the screen is loaded and I try to access the job name occurs an exception:

undefined is not an object

How can I fetch data from an API and render properly ?
Thanks.

Comment: Which line does your error correspond to?

Comment: Sorry. The line is: this.state.job.name

Comment: `return (<Text>{this.state.job && this.state.job.name? this.state.job.name : null }</Text>)`

Comment: I think that you should check what `res.job` is. It should be an object, ideally with a property `name`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `fetch` is asynchronous, your view will try to render and is looking for `name` which does not exist yet. You can have a `Loading...` state for this if you wish in your `render` method, like so -

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.job.name) {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }

  return (<Text>{this.state.job.name}</Text>);
}
```

Comment: `job.name` will be undefined on first render but I don't see why that should cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is asynchronous, and the first `render` will occur before the state is set. Until then, `this.state.job.name` is undefined.

However, I think your error might actually come from the way you're handling the response, and that you're setting `this.state.job` to undefined. Note that the code below is asynchronous but produces no error, even before `this.state.job.name` is defined.

You need to make sure that you're handling your response correctly and setting `this.state.job` to an object, otherwise you will get an exception when you try and access the `name` property.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        job: {}
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({
        job: {
          name: "job"
        }
      }), 1000);
    }

    render() {
      return (<p>{this.state.job.name}</p>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/> , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```